# Multiple queues not being created - C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, queue, message-queue

At first i was creating this program to cater for one queue, and everything was working. I currently am trying to create multiple queues, by using an array of structure with each queue being identified with it's own ID. But as it seems it is still only creating only one queue(as when i use a function with listing all the queues it is only listing one) and i need some help in fixing it. The code can be found below:

```
    #define MAX_MESSAGES 5
    #define MAX_MSG_LEN 20
    #define MAX_QUEUES 5

    typedef struct queue{
        int front, rear, size;
        char elements[MAX_MESSAGES][MAX_MSG_LEN];
    }queue_t;

    typedef struct MsgQs{
        int id;
        queue_t *qs[MAX_QUEUES];
    }MsgQs_t;


int main(){
int id, i = 0;

    MsgQs_t *qs = initializeMsgQs_t();
    //MsgQs_t *qs = NULL;
    queue_t *pq = NULL;

while(1){
        printf("\n1) Create new queue");
        printf("\n0) Quit");
        printf("\nEnter choice:");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        getchar();

        switch(choice){
            case '1': //createQ
                printf("\nCreating a queue!\nEnter Queue-ID (Ex. 1234):");
                scanf("%d", &qs[i].id);
                pq = createQ(qs[i].id);
                printf("Queue with ID %d has been created successfully!\n", qs[i].id);
                i++;
                break;
            case '0':
                printf("\nQuitting");
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Incorrect. Re-enter.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}

MsgQs_t* initializeMsgQs_t(){
    MsgQs_t* qs = malloc(sizeof(MsgQs_t));

    return qs;
}

queue_t* createQ(){

    queue_t* pq = malloc (sizeof(queue_t));

    pq -> front = 0;
    pq -> rear = 0;
    pq -> size = 0;

    return pq;
}
```

I have many more functions regarding these multiple queues although i minimized the program to indicate the first problem i have in my program.

Comment: Are you sure you are only creating 1?  At `pq = createQ(qs[i].id);`, it looks like you are creating many, but replacing `pq` with the new one each iteration.

Comment: @Jason i am not 100% sure, i think you are right. How would i fix it to not replace with each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line here is creating a memory leak:

```
pq = createQ(qs[i].id);
```

`createQ` is returning a valid pointer to an instance of `queue_t` and assigning it to `pq`.  However, on the next iteration, `pq` will be assigned to a new instance of `queue_t`. `pq` can only point to a single instance of `queue_t`, so instance from the last iteration is no longer reachable.  This is a classic memory leak.  There are a handful of approaches to fix this, but it boils down to having more than one pointer to `queue_t`.  It looks like you took a stab at a correct approach with the `MsgQs_t` structure.  I will provide a solution that fits with what it looks like you were trying to do.

First this definition:

```
typedef struct MsgQs{
    int id;
    queue_t *qs[MAX_QUEUES];
}MsgQs_t;
```

When you create an instance of `MsgQs_t`, you now have an array `queue_t*` of a fixed size `MAX_QUEUES`.  The `malloc` in createQ is over-writing this array of queue_t*.  You've already allocated space for your pointers when you instantiate `MsgQs_t`.  This is just a misunderstanding of the stack vs. heap allocation.  Here is a simpler example with `char*`.

```
char* charptr = malloc(10);  /* heap allocation requires malloc */
char chararray[10];          /* This is ALREADY allocated 10 chars on the stack */
```

So you could just assign directly to the struct member `qs`.  It's hard to tell, but it looks like your intention was to actually have 1 `id` per queue.  If that is the case, your struct definition should look like this:

```
typedef struct MsgQs{
    int id;
    queue_t *msgQueue; /* changed name to avoid confusion */
}MsgQs_t;
```

You also want to change the `malloc` size in `initializeMsgQs_t`:

```
//This allocates MAX_QUEUES MsgQs_t structs
MsgQs_t* qs = malloc(MAX_QUEUES * sizeof(MsgQs_t));

//This only allocates 1:
MsgQs_t* qs = malloc(sizeof(MsgQs_t));
```

Now, you have a heap allocated array of `MAX_QUEUES` structs of type `MsgQs_t`.  Then, you can assign to them directly in the loop.  Below, is a re-written version of the loop.  I changed the while loop because we don't want to loop passed MAX_QUEUES.  Accessing `qs[MAX_QUEUES]` will be undefined behavior and likely result in a segmentation fault.

```
while (i < MAX_QUEUES) {
    printf("\n1) Create new queue");
    printf("\n0) Quit");
    printf("\nEnter choice: ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    getchar();

    switch(choice) {
        case '1': //createQ
            printf("\nCreating a queue!\nEnter Queue-ID (Ex. 1234):");
            scanf("%d", &qs[i].id);
            getchar();
            qs[i].msgQueue = createQ();
            printf("Queue with ID %d has been created successfully!\n", qs[i].id);
            i++;
            break;
        case '0':
            printf("\nQuitting");
            exit(1);
        default:
            printf("Incorrect. Re-enter.\n");
            break;
    }
}
```